# How to implement multi key lookup

Tags: scala, dictionary

I need a data structure that I lookup using two keys.

What are the pro and con of each choice ?

- `Map[K1, Map[K2, V]]`
- `Map[(K1, K2), V]`

It seems that the latter solution will require instantiation of a lot of tuples : `get(k1, k2) = m.get((k1,k2))`

The use case is a cache, so obviously more read than write, and `Map` are `scala.collection.concurrent.Map`

Comment: Do you ever look up  by k1 only? Do you ever want to know which key-pairs start with a certain first-key?

Comment: I always lookup with both keys

Comment: Then in my view, for your application, "*(K1,K2)" is non-decomposable (as far as this data structure is concerned) and you should go for your second option as it makes this more explicit. But really, I suspect there are more important decisions to be making, it doesn't matter much

Comment: " will require instantiation of a lot of tuples". Maybe, It depends on whether the tuples are naturally the right thing in other areas of your app. We really can't tell much from this limited information

Comment: My app doesn't manage tuples, cf the signature of the `get` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect that for each K1 there will be many K2, but not the other way around, the first may be better. It will use more memory because you have two map structures and you'll have more pointer indirection, though that's unlikely to matter.

The latter is what I'd use because it more closely represents what you're trying to do.